# getting output of a query in sqlite - android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

you get data out of the columns using pre-provided methods such as `getInt(...)`, `getString(...)`, but how do you get data out of something like a `SELECT` statement, in `sqlite` the statement I'd like to do something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM TABLE_NAME
```

how would you execute this query and then get the result to an `int` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it the same way:

```
String sql = "SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM TABLE_NAME";
```

So if you create a `Cursor` object  with `rawQuery()`:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
```

this `Cursor` contains only 1 column and you can get its value with:

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) result = c.getInt(0);
```

where `result` is a predefined `int` variable.
But it's a good practice to alias the returned column, like:

```
String sql = "SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) AS counter FROM TABLE_NAME";
```

so you can get it  by its name:

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) result = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("counter"));
```

Comment: I didnt ask it in the main question, but do you know if android provides a way to select the nth row in a table, or should we use something like the `limit` clause and select the last row?

Comment: You must use limit but with an ORDER BY clause, like: `select * from tablename order by id limit 10`

Comment: but use the order by? the LIMIT clause disorganizes rows?(I'm not very familiar with sql itself)

Comment: Tables are unordered datasets. What you think as first 10 rows might not be what you will get with: `select * from tablename limit 10`. You can do it but there is no guarantee for the result.

Comment: it is true with general sql or just with sqlite(in android or in general?)

Comment: This applies to any rdbms that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Dao CLASS which include count method which returns count of the TABLE_NAME

```
@Dao
abstract class TABLE_NAMEDao : BaseDao<TABLE_NAME> {
@Query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM TABLE_NAME")
    abstract fun count(): Long
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand kotlin, would it be possible to also provide the java version alongside?